# GXT FillToolItem

Tags: gxt, gwt-ext

The FillToolItem , fills the toolbar width, pushing any newly added items to the **right**.

```
public FillToolItem() {
    getAriaSupport().setPresentation(true);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onRender(Element target, int index) {
    setElement(DOM.createDiv(), target, index);
  }
```

I want to create a new class LeftFillToolItem that will extend the FillToolItem , but  will pushing any newly added items to the **left**. 
how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I can't seem to understand your question can you give an example. By default(when a FillToolItem is not inserted) new items are already added to the left.